# Capybara + Rspec + Poltergeist: field not found, crazy javascript in my page with an iframe to my actual page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

Update: I just tried the capybara-webkit driver...

and did a puts page.html... and got REALLY weird links

```
<a href="/track/adclick.php?curl=http%3A%2F%2F2586831.r.msn.com%2F%3Fld%3D8vBu5GdQd4kexMalZqHcYPmDVUCUyQANoHj2Thi7CB49kGqg45E_13jW8kWhJ3oFryF7SRaVKRasDO9OGT2j42V_4OCDVdtO0D5ZEXO9TXjg05qq0nYk4Y-APihWn7J6o43xUTn0FslIdjbT8h3cysucakxeA%26u%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252ftracker.marinsm.com%252frd%253fcid%253d529lae2415%2526mkwid%253ddPfP7vII%2526pcrid%253d3168867153%2526lp%253dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.littlewoods.com%25252Falice-in-wonderland-blu-ray-double-play-blu-ray-dvd--includes-free-alice-in-wonderland-poster%25252F734955273.prd%253faff%253dmsn%2526affsrc%253dacquisition%2526cm_mmc%253d-_--_-Alice%252bin%252bWonderland%252bDVDs%252b%252528BMM%252529-_-%252balice%2B%252bin%2B%252bwonderland_dPfP7vII_3168867153&amp;q=test1.tinderbox.vhost&amp;head=%3Cb%3EAlice%3C%2Fb%3E+%3Cb%3Ein%3C%2Fb%3E+%3Cb%3EWonderland%3C%2Fb%3E+DVDs+%7C+littlewoods.com&amp;network=yahoodm&amp;ad_grp=TOP&amp;ad_grp_pos=1&amp;type=domain_query&amp;ifc=0&amp;host=www.littlewoods.com%2Fdvds&amp;loadtime=1384544309" style="color:black; text-decoration:none" target="_top">Looking For DVDs with Free Returns Then Look No Further!</a>
```

What is going on?! There are no ads in my app.. and I wouldn't be caught dead linking to msn or yahoo.

---

I have this:

require "spec_helper"

feature "Tracking without Javascript", js: true do

```
before(:each) do
        ...
    visit(
        sub_domain(
            path: login_view_path(
                @p
            ),
            subdomain: @account.subdomain
        )
    )

    puts page.html
```

and the output looks something like this:

```
<html><head>
        <script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script><title>  </title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function bredir(a, b, c, d, e, ldr, ifc) {
                var h, i, j;
                var f = 0;
                var g = 0;
                var k = false;
                var l = false;
                var m = [
                    [300, 250, false],
                    [250, 250, false],
                    [240, 400, false],
                    [336, 280, false],
                    [180, 150, false],
                    [468, 60, false],
                    [234, 60, false],
                    [88, 31, false],
                    [120, 90, false],
                    [120, 60, false],
                    [120, 240, false],
                    [125, 125, false],
                    [728, 90, false],
                    [160, 600, false],
                    [120, 600, false],
                    [300, 600, false],
                    [300, 125, false],
                    [530, 300, false],
                    [190, 200, false],
                    [470, 250, false],
                    [720, 300, true],
                    [500, 350, true],
                    [550, 480, true],
                    //YouTube:
                    [560, 315, true],
                    [640, 360, true],
                    [853, 480, true],
                    [1280, 720, true],
                    //Vimeo:
                    [400, 300, true],
                    [500, 281, true],
                    //Hulu:
                    [480, 270, true],
                    [512, 288, true],
                    //metacafe:
                    [440, 248, true],
                    [460, 284, true],
                    [540, 304, true],
                    [600, 338, true],
                    //Other dimensions (metacafe, myspace video, yahoo video, break.com, ustream, vevo, justin.tv, etc):
                    [210, 120, true],
                    [400, 300, true],
                    [425, 350, true],
                    [425, 360, true],
                    [435, 251, true],
                    [435, 271, true],
                    [500, 300, true],
                    [525, 295, true],
                    [575, 324, true],
                    [620, 389, true],
                    [624, 351, true],
                    [630, 381, true],
                    [640, 385, true],
                    [650, 368, true],
                    [1000, 562, true],
                    [1000, 563, true],
                    [1000, 564, true]
                ];
                if (typeof window.innerHeight == "number") {
                    g = window.innerHeight;
                    f = window.innerWidth;
                } else if (typeof document.body.offsetHeight == "number") {
                    g = document.body.offsetHeight;
                    f = document.body.offsetWidth;
                }
                for (var n = 0; n < m.length; n++) {
                    j = m[n];
                    h = Math.abs(f - j[0]);
                    i = Math.abs(g - j[1]);
                    if (top != self) {
                        ifc = 1;
                    } else {
                        ifc = 0;
                    };
                    if (h <= 2 && i <= 2) {
                        k = true;
                        l = j[2]
                    }
                }
                if(f === 0 && g === 0){
                    return;
                }
                if ((a != "www.facebook.com" && a != "platform.twitter.com") && (k || f < 100 && f !== 0 || g < 100 && g !== 0)) {
                    if (l && self == parent) {
                        return;
                    }
                    return "/b" + "anner.php?w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&d=" + a + "&url=" + b + "&ref=" + c + "&view=" + d
                } else if ((a == "www.facebook.com" || a == "platform.twitter.com") && (f >= 250 && g >= 60) && (k || f < 100 && f !== 0 || g < 100 && g !== 0)) {
                    if (l && self == parent) {
                        return;
                    }
                    return e + "&w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&ldr=" + "b" + "&ifc=" + ifc;
                } else if ((a == "www.facebook.com" || a == "platform.twitter.com") && (f < 250 || g < 60) && (k || f < 100 && f !== 0 || g < 100 && g !== 0)) {
                    if (l && self == parent) {
                        return;
                    }
                    return "/b" + "anner.php?w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&d=" + a + "&url=" + b + "&ref=" + c + "&view=" + d;
                } else {
                    return e + "&w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&ifc=" + ifc;
                }
            }
            function bdetect() {
                var loc = bredir(
                    'test1.tinderbox.vhost', 
                    'test1.tinderbox.vhost%2Fview%2Falice-in-wonderland-14-years-later%2Flogin', 
                    '', 
                    'error', 
                    '/main?wc=EWJvEwFmDRpfAhxuAA%3D%3D&url=test1.tinderbox.vhost%2Fview%2Falice-in-wonderland-14-years-later%2Flogin'
                );

                if(typeof loc === 'undefined') {
                    self.close();
                    return;
                }

                location.replace(loc);

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="bdetect()" style="margin: 0px;">
        <noscript>
            &lt;iframe frameborder="0" src="/main?wc=EWJvEwFmDRpfAhxuAA%3D%3D&amp;amp;url=test1.tinderbox.vhost%2Fview%2Falice-in-wonderland-14-years-later%2Flogin" width="100%" height="100%"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
        </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">if(!NREUMQ.f){NREUMQ.f=function(){NREUMQ.push(["load",new Date().getTime()]);var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.src=(("http:"===document.location.protocol)?"http:":"https:")+"//"+"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-100.js";document.body.appendChild(e);if(NREUMQ.a)NREUMQ.a();};NREUMQ.a=window.onload;window.onload=NREUMQ.f;};NREUMQ.push(["nrfj","beacon-6.newrelic.com","01957cb5b6","2615933","YlxaMhZTCERSUUwIClsWbRQNHQ9ZV1dATxVdSQ==",0,4,new Date().getTime(),"","","","",""]);</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-100.js"></script></body></html>
```

what is this? and why is it happening?

it's causing `Capybara::ElementNotFound` when I try to use `fill_in`